# clang-format: add two spaces after private (public)

Tags: clang-format

I'm using clang-format to format code. I would like to know if it is possible to add two space after private(public).

clang-famart version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1

---

Now it's like this

```cpp
class Test
{
  public:
  Test();
  private:
  std::string str;
}
```

this is what i expecting(using space not using tab!):

```cpp
class Test
{
  public:
    Test();
  private:
    std::string str;
}
```

this is my .clang-format:

```json
{ 
  BasedOnStyle: LLVM,
  UseTab: Never,
  IndentWidth: 2,
  PointerAlignment: Left,
  SortIncludes: false,
  ObjCSpaceAfterProperty:true ,
  TabWidth: 0, 
  BreakBeforeBraces: Allman, 
  AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false, 
  IndentCaseLabels: false, 
  ColumnLimit: 0, 
  AccessModifierOffset: 0, 
  NamespaceIndentation: All,
  FixNamespaceComments: false 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IndentAccessModifiers](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#:%7E:text=record%20members%20are%20always%20indented%202%20levels%20below%20the%20record) should do the trick, but you may need to update to clang-format-13:

```
IndentAccessModifiers: true
```